# Allow CALL_PHONE permission on devices with no phone

Tags: android, permissions

My application uses the CALL_PHONE permission so that it can directly place calls.  Making calls is not the main feature and the app is still useful without that ability.  However, the Android store will filter-out my app if the user's device does not have telephony.  How do I configure the app so that the user can find and download the app anyway?

I realize I could publish two apps.  I would like to avoid that and keep my build & release process simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `CALL_PHONE` permission will automatically include the `telephony` feature, which is what the market uses to filter out tablets. You'll need to make it optional by including the following in your manifest:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />`

Comment: It's a fun little thing to find the first time. Make sure you do check whether the feature is available prior to using it, or it'll crash your app; the preferred pattern is to disable or hide the feature-related UI (i.e. no CALL icon on tablets).